# Why do we need to decrement iterator while deleting from vector?

Tags: c++, erase

I have a below program. I need to understand why do we need to decrement pointer when we use erase method?
Also is there any better way which does not create a  such confusion ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 

int main()
{
    vector<int> myvector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
 
    for (auto i = myvector.begin(); i != myvector.end(); ++i) {
        if (*i % 2 == 0) {
            myvector.erase(i);
            i--;// why do we need to decrement ?
        }
    }
 
    // Printing the vector
    for (auto it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to understand why do we need to decrement pointer when we use erase method?

You don't, and shouldn't. The correct thing to do is use the return value of `erase`. At the moment your program has undefined behaviour because you are modifying an invalid iterator.

```
for (auto i = myvector.begin(); i != myvector.end();) {
    if (*i % 2 == 0) {
        i = myvector.erase(i);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

> Also is there any better way which does not create a such confusion ?

Yes, [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

```
auto is_even = [](int i){ return (i % 2) == 0; };
auto last = std::remove_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), is_even);
myvector.erase(last, myvector.end());
```

Comment: in this { i = myvector.erase(i);}, now where exactly i is pointing to , next valid one or the one before ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I mean to say ,for an eg auto myiterator = myvector.erase(i), where does this "myiterator" is pointing to  now?

Comment: @unixlover It refers to the element that used to be after the one that was removed. In other words, for an `std::vector`, it refers to the object that is now at the index the removed element used to occupy.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks Buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a good answer from Caleth, but I'm going to add some information:

```
for (auto i = myvector.begin(); i != myvector.end(); ++i) {
    if (*i % 2 == 0) {
        myvector.erase(i);
        i--;// why do we need to decrement ?
    }
}
```

That's your code. For my explanation, let's believe that the iterator is just an index (an int). It's not, but it works for understanding.

Let's say myvector contains the integers 0..10 and you delete 4. Once you do:

```
0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Now, imagine your loop. You get to the bottom of the for-loop and increment i -- it now has 5, but you skip over checking if the old myvector[5] -- which is now stored in myvector[4] -- fits your if-statement.

The other way to write this:

for (auto i = myvector.begin(); i != myvector.end(); ) {
if (...) ...
else {
++i;
}
}

That is, you only increment the iterator if you do NOT delete. This avoids skipping over the item after the one you deleted (because it moved into the deleted guy's spot).

However, this is the wrong way to do it, and Caleth has better answers for how to do it properly.